# Why array state change is not rendering again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was following the React learn section when i encountered this.
I´m drawing three shapes from an array called shapes. I modify the entire array when i press the button and the array do change when i do this.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MyApp() {
  const initialShapes = [
    { name: "circle", x: 50, y: 10, id: 1 },
    { name: "square", x: 100, y: 10, id: 2 },
    { name: "circle", x: 150, y: 10, id: 3 },
  ];
  const [shapes, setShapes] = useState(initialShapes);
  console.log(shapes);
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShapes([{ name: "square", x: 20, y: 70, id: 2 }]);
        }}
      >
        Just show one shape
      </button>
      {initialShapes.map((shape) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={shape.id}
            style={
              shape.name === "circle"
                ? {
                    position: "absolute",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    width: "30px",
                    height: "30px",
                    borderRadius: "50px",
                    translate: `${shape.x}px ${shape.y}px`,
                  }
                : {
                    position: "absolute",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    width: "30px",
                    height: "30px",
                    translate: `${shape.x}px ${shape.y}px`,
                  }
            }
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

I can verify this by the console log at the beginning of the component. The state does uptade indeed but my visual shapes don't uptade with the new state.

> const [shapes, setShapes] = useState(initialShapes);
> console.log(shapes);
> return (..
> Console on first state

```
[
    {
        "name": "circle",
        "x": 50,
        "y": 10,
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "square",
        "x": 100,
        "y": 10,
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "circle",
        "x": 150,
        "y": 10,
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

Console on second state

```
[
    {
        "name": "square",
        "x": 20,
        "y": 70,
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

I know that if it was a mutation to the array, re-rendering won't be trigger but i'm actually setting a new state.
Why does this happen, react shouldn't notice the difference between array changes and trigger the render again ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `shapes` variable, you are mapping `initialShapes`.